# drupal 7 register form alter submit

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

i am just adding the user_type element in the signup form. i want to insert that user_type in the user_roles table.

Getting error

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

```
function bartik_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $result = db_query("SELECT name, rid FROM role where rid > 3");
  foreach ($result as $row){
    $option[$row->rid] = $row->name;
  }

  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    $form['user_type'] = array(
      '#type'=>'select',
      '#title' => t('User Type'),
      '#options' => $option,
      '#multiple' => false,
      '#attributes'=>array('size'=>0),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['#submit'][] = 'bartik_form_alter_submit'
  }
}

/**
 * Additional handler for user_login form submit.
 */



function  bartik_form_alter_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    if (isset($form_state['values']['user_type'])){
        $LastCreatedUsername = $form_state['values']['name'];
        $fetch_uid_arr = db_select('users', 'u')
                ->fields('u', array('uid'))
                ->condition('name', $LastCreatedUsername, '=')
                ->execute()
                ->fetchAssoc();

        $uid = $fetch_uid_arr['uid'];
        $rid = $form_state['values']['user_type'];
        $nid = db_insert('users_roles') 
               ->fields(array('uid' => $uid,'rid' => $rid,))
               ->execute();
    }   
}
```

Updated Status: As per @Ben suggestion, i have modified the snippet, in registration page selected roles are updated into table.

Please provide your suggestion / feedback for my updated code. is it the right way to insert roles into drupal table.

i have tried the above snippet in freshly installed drupal application. To save the singup form system tooks nearly 4min. Drupal version 7.24

Comment: It sounds like your additional hooks might just be the "straw that broke the camels back". You should verify that without your code, the application is not already running near to the 30 seconds; due to another bug or issue.

Comment: there is no bug, i removed the above code, site working fine.

Comment: " site working fine"; sure. But does it run, like 2x.xx seconds? If so, adding your code, could trigger Drupal into running certain hooks, which then pushes the total runtime just above that 30 seconds.

Comment: As per your response, Is my code is correct ?

Comment: Try https://github.com/fotuzlab/appgati to find the resources this function is using.

Comment: My second guess would be that either `SELECT name, rid FROM role where rid > 3` is returning a lot of records (several thousands), which would not be normal in Drupal; can you confirm this? Or else the hook `bartik_form_alter` is being called in a loop. You can test this by e.g. printing `print "bartik_form_alter<br/>"` in the hook and determining if it appears more then once in your output.

Comment: that sql query will return only 4 records,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't have thought it's slowing your site down by 30 seconds but one obvious problem with your code is that you're building the roles for every single form. You should do the form id check first like so:

```
<?php
function bartik_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    $result = db_query("SELECT name, rid FROM role where rid > 3");
    foreach ($result as $row){
      $option[$row->rid] = $row->name;
    }

    $form['user_type'] = array(
      '#type'=>'select',
      '#title' => t('User Type'),
      '#options' => $option,
      '#multiple' => false,
      '#attributes'=>array('size'=>0),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );
  }
}
```

You could also just use `bartik_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state)` which targets that specific form.

I'd also recommend using Devel and Xhprof to see where all the execution time is been spent.

Comment: Your suggestion is correct, SQL is reason for my problem. but still my submit not working, i put " EXIT  " in the above submit inside isset , but no response / halt, application just creating new user, what is the hook function for alter form submit

Comment: Within your `hook_form_alter` add `$form['#submit'][] = 'bartik_form_alter_submit'` and that should work.